# Can't connect to remote server from FireFox but works in IE & Chrome

Tags: html, firefox, web

I have some html to connect to server's(Remote server path's) like this

```
           <TABLE BORDER="5"  WIDTH="90%" CELLPADDING="4" CELLSPACING="3">
       <TR>
          <TH COLSPAN="2"><BR><H4><Font color=GREEN><b>CIT</b></FONT></H4></TH>
       </TR>
       <TR>
          <TH COLSPAN="2">123</TH>
      <TH></TH>
       </TR>
       <TR ALIGN="CENTER">
          <TD COLSPAN="2"><a href=http://123.abc.com/apps>Eformer</a></TD>
       </TR>
       <TR ALIGN="CENTER">
      <TD><a href=http://123.abc.com/apps/way>Gateway - PULSE</a></TD>
      <TD><a href=http://123.abc.com/apps/gate>Gateway - HONDA</a></TD>
       </TR>
       <TR ALIGN="CENTER">
      <TD><a href=http://123.abc.com/apps/mm>Fax - PULSE</a></TD>
      <TD><a href=http://123.abc.com/apps/mn>Fax - HONDA</a></TD>
       </TR>
        <TR ALIGN="CENTER">
      <TD><a href=http://123.abc.com/apps/pulse>TYPE - PULSE</a></TD>
       </TR>
       <TR ALIGN="CENTER">
      <TD><a href=http://123.abc.com/apps/xy>POST - PULSE</a></TD>
      <TD><a href=http://123.abc.com/apps/yz>POST - HONDA</a></TD>
       </TR>
       <TR ALIGN="CENTER">
      <TD><a href=http://123.abc.com/apps/ss>Agent - PULSE</a></TD>
       </TR>
    </TABLE>
```

This works in IE & Chrome but doesn't work in Firefox. Can someone extend their kind help to work out?

Comment: Maybe you should put commas on the paths? - 
href="http://123.abc.com/apps/ss"

Comment: I would love to hear that firefox dropped support for bad HTML *sigh*

Comment: This is the classical problem when dealing in invalid HTML: you have no guarantee that all browsers will apply the same fixes. But I've tested your snippet with Firefox and all links show up with the correct URL. Unless you explain how this code fails to meet your expectations, there's no way to answer this question.

Comment: It should work in all the IE,Chrome & FireFox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally,i've found it. There is variation in format to work in firefox.We need to include 5 forward slashes to work in firefox.Here is the example

```
<a href ="file://///123/APPS/path"> Eformer </a>
```

For our example it should be formatted as  -

```
<TD><a href="file://///123/APPS/xy">POST - PULSE</a></TD>
<TD><a href="file://///123/APPS/yz">POST - HONDA</a></TD>
```

where 123 is server name and no need to specify domain(abc.com) in our above example.
This works in all IE,Chrome & Firefox browswers.

Comment: `We need to include 5 forward slashes to work in firefox` where did you find? from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/)?

Answer (score 0):

Links in `href` must be enclosed in `""` as

```
<a href="http://123.abc.com/apps"></a>
```

Read more about using links [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html). Also link url must not be broken on server end.

Answer (score 0):

All mentioned browsers are capable of handling invalid HTML and opening your links in an appropriate manner. `<a href="http://blabla.com/one/two">link</a>` is one of the oldest HTML tags and core functionality of HTML and works even if you are using very old versions of browsers.

As a good analyist, there must be something different going wrong; I can imagine 3 cases:

1. You are using a missconfigured proxy (from school or business) which has a problem with your paths.
2. Your browser(s) openes the url correct, but your server redirects to a different (wrong/unexpected) path due to missconfiguration
3. You have installed a firewall / antivirus / proxy / plugin which changes the URI in the HTTP request to something unexpected

Good luck on your mission Mr. Hunt. This message will self destruct in 5, ..4, ...3, ...

Comment: Good analysis....will try to solve this soon.
I dont understand why FireFox only has different set of rules/configuration

Comment: I'm pretty sure firefox does not have a different rule or configuration. Not for something like a simple link. Did you open the error console and see if it throws an error? Which exact version of firefox do you use? Mine is 23.0.1 and links do work. Maybe you can post a link to your exact HTML so we can see if there is an error..

Comment: Im using 4.0.1 & 22.0 in another system. I find same problem with links (connect remote server/location) from other system too. I've opened Error Console & found error saying "Components.classes['@mozilla.org/extensions/manager',1] is undefined"

Comment: In FireFox 22.0 version, i found error saying - "
Error: The character encoding of the HTML document was not declared. The document will render with garbled text in some browser configurations if the document contains characters from outside the US-ASCII range. The character encoding of the page must be declared in the document or in the transfer protocol.
Source File: file:///D:app/ab.html
Line: 0 "

Comment: What exactly happens when you click on a link with firefox? Does the URL change in the navigation?

Comment: No, it remains unchanged